# How to add search dropdown for sharepoint site collection by powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have a few custom search scopes that I wanted to add dropdownlist for search box and advanced search. It can be done manually by editing View scopes > Display Groups but I want to change it by using powershell script. What is possible approach I could have?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28306/edit-search-dropdown-scopedisplaygroup-with-powershell-unauthorized

Look at the comments and create a whole script that way.  Alternatively, look at the C# version (and convert to psh!): 
http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/04/creating-sharepoint-2010-search-scopes-programmatically/

Cheers.